# codeigniter routes

Tags: codeigniter, routes

need next:
I use codeigniter 2.02
I removes index.php with htaccess

I have controller post and with route

`$route['(:any)'] = "post/index/$1";`

And I get what I want: domain.com/14 in place of domain.com/post/14

BUT now I have next controllers that I want like: login, member etc.

But if I go to domain.com/login I'm redirected to domain.com ... so if someone can get me solution so I can go to login controller... with some regular expression with routes!

this is my routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:any)'] = "post/index/$1";
$route['signup/(:any)'] = "signup/index/$1";
```

and hier is what effect I need:

```
domain.com/camera-33455-cannon-2001
domain.com/samsung-6678-new-gallaxy-2
```

and also to get other controllers like

```
domain.com/signup
```

tnx

Answer (score 3):

The routes are handled in the order in which they appear on your `routes.php` file. So if you put your controllers on top, `(:any)` should just handle anything that is not previously handled.

Try changing it to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['signup/(:any)'] = "signup/index/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "post/index/$1";
```

Comment: this is what I have
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:any)'] = "m/index/$1";
$route['signup/(:any)'] = "signup/index/$1";

but id doesn't work

Comment: Try playing with the syntax as per this page: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I'm trying this for a couple of months...but didn't found it...and I begon with that url you suggested

Answer (score 2):

Do you only want numbers for the `post/index` route?  You might be better off using this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['signup/(:any)'] = "signup/index/$1";
$route['(:num)'] = "post/index/$1";
```

This way, `/15` will redirect to `/post/index/15`, but `/bob` will still load the `Bob` controller.

Comment: this is thing I want to have:
domain.com/camera-33455-cannon-2001

Comment: is there a way to say in that route if you see signup...do not ignore it! so for every made controller I could make route

Comment: OK, well, you should update your question to reflect what you actually want.  (Personally, I think it would look better to leave it as `/post/camera-33455-cannon-2001`, but that's just opinion.)