# Codeigniter routes subfolder not working

Tags: codeigniter, routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";

$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['(:any)'] = 'index/$1';

$route['admin'] = "admin/index"; 

$route['admin/add_category'] = "admin/index/add_category";
```

**Works :**

```
$route['admin/edit_category/2']  = "admin/index/edit_category/2";
```

**Not working :**

```
$route['admin/edit_category/(:any)']  = "admin/index/edit_category/$1";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070500/codeigniter-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put Your rule before route which catches everything

```
$route['admin'] = "admin/index"; // no params at first

$route['admin/add_category'] = "admin/index/add_category"; // extend first rule

$route['admin/edit_category/(:any)']  = "admin/index/edit_category/$1"; // and one more

$route['default_controller'] = "index"; // default settings

$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['(:any)'] = 'index/$1'; // ok, now we can brake MVC pattern, but should we?
```

for example one of my route-files (works for sure):

```
$route['project-admin/login'] = "project-cms/user/index";
$route['project-admin/recovery'] = "project-cms/user/recovery";
$route['project-admin'] = "project-cms/admin/index";
$route['project-admin/(:any)'] = "project-cms/admin/$1";
$route['project-admin/(:any)/(:any)'] = "project-cms/admin/$1/$2";
```